# Implicit AsQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The following linq2entities code would appear to call the IEnumerable version of FirstOrDefault extension, because PersonHistories is an ICollection.  At runtime however, it actually calls the IQueryable version.

```
var test = db.Persons.Where(d => d.PersonKey == 4)
        .Select(f => f.PersonHistories.FirstOrDefault());
```

The problem I am having is the custom query provider I am using does not perform this automatic conversion, and I get the error "...ICollection cannot be used for parameter of type IQueryable".  Thus requires explicitly calling AsQueryable to work around this, but for complex queries it gets very redundant and not feeling very DRY:

```
db.Persons.Where(d => d.PersonKey == 4)
        .Select(f => f.PersonHistories.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault());
```

I have dug around in the framework reference source trying to find the Linq 2 Entities visitors/provider stuff, but have had no luck(perhaps is not part of any of the open reference sources).  **How do the base providers accomplish this implicit use of AsQueryable?**

---

I do understand that these are translated to expression trees.
I do understand that the Enumerable.FirstOrDefault is replaced with Queryable.FirstOrDefault by the provider.  That is the premise of the question.

Comment: Try flipping it around and see it "just works": `db.Persons.Where(d => d.PersonKey == 4).PersonHistories.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, because .Where returns a collection/IQueryable, on which there is no such PersonHistories field.  You would have to use something like SingleOrDefault to get a single item, or a .Select to project the nested fields.  I chose to demo the issue with a nested projection because this is where I run into the problem.  Since db.Persons is a DbSet then it is IQueryable and thus the .Where is automatically the IQueryable versions, but in contrast Person.PersonHistories is implemented as an ICollection and is a bit more challenging to handle.

Answer (score 2):

> How do the base providers accomplish this implicit use of AsQueryable?

They don't. Your code doesn't *really* execute `FirstOrDefault()` at all. It builds an *expression tree* which represents the call, but that isn't executed directly. The query provider sees that, works out that the `f.PersonHistories` is actually based on an entity which is in the database, and converts the query appropriately.

Comment: So does the expression tree contain separate branches for `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: The expression tree itself will contain a reference to the method being called, which is either `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` or `Queryable.FirstOrDefault`. In this case the tree will actually refer to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`, but good providers will handle it anyway.

Comment: I understand it is converted into an expression tree, but the expression tree does actually include a `.Call System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault`(when using the default provider).  But how does it know to do this?  My question is, how does it discover the Queryable version instead of the IEnumerable version?  The code for the Queryable version of FirstOrDefault does indeed construct an expression, but the IEnumerable version doesn't perform any such check.  Where is the mechanism that allows it to make that jump?

Comment: @AaronLS: Really? Are you sure? I don't see how it can if `f.PersonHistories` doesn't implement `IQueryable`. How did you determine that?

Comment: @Jon I modified my post.  I can mouse over the `test` variable after executing the statement and inspect the expression debug view.

Comment: @AaronLS: I wouldn't trust that. That's not the expression tree your code builds - it's the expression tree that the *provider* has built based on the one it's given. Look with Reflector or something similar, and I'm sure you'll see the call to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Jon Yes I understood that, which is what lead me to come here and post to ask what the mechanism is that the default provider uses to replace the Enumerable.FirstOrDefault with a Queryable.FirstOrDefault.  The provider I am using(which inherits from the default and passes many calls down to the base) is breaking this so that I must now sprinkle `AsQueryable` all over my queries.  I think we got off on the wrong track because I was trying to make the distinction that the expression does indeed contain a call to FirstOrDefault, whereas you were stating it did not, but maybe I misread.

Comment: @AaronLS: I was stating that the expression tree *generated by the compiler* includes a call to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`, not `Queryable.FirstOrDefault`. The mechanism for what the EF provider does when it sees a call to `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` is an implementation detail really.

Comment: @Jon That "implementation detail" is exactly what I am after.  Hence why I happened to mention looking for the reference source with this implementation.  If I am inheriting from something, and I am breaking one of its features, I really have to dig into the details of how that feature works in order to understand how to fix/unbreak it.

Comment: @AaronLS: I don't think you'll find any source for the EF provider online. You could see whether NHibernate does this as well though. It's not clear what "custom query provider" you're using - is this one you're able to modify?

Comment: @Jon Yes I can modify it. It basically looks for custom extension methods that are tagged with a certain attribute, and if so replaces them with a compatible expression(since linq2entities would choke on custom extension methods).  For the most part passes most everything down to the base provider.  Unfortunately, often when I'm trying to step into the base code with the .NET reflector or even the Reference source debug symbols, either way, I am getting disassembly.